# How to import the fonts in react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fonts

```
src: url(../fonts/icons.woff) format("woff");
```

The fonts are not loading when i tried to import it locally in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ***fonts*** folder is inside the ***src*** and the ***app.css*** is inside the ***src*** then you should remove the `..` from the path

change `src: url(../fonts/icons.woff) format("woff");` to `src: url(fonts/icons.woff) format("woff");`

The path to assets from the ***css*** files is relative to the actual ***css*** file.